# Lógica de button e span a partir de CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, css3

Eu tenho um `button` e um `span` a partir do seguinte código:

```
<div id="onestepcheckout-place-order">
      <button type="button" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order Now'); ?>" id="onestepcheckout-place-order-button">
            <span><span class="onestepcheckout-place-order-title"><?php echo $this->__('Place Order'); ?></span></span>
            <span class="onestepcheckout-place-order-amount hide hidden" ><?php echo $this->getGrandTotal(); ?></span>
      </button>
</div>
<span id="process" style="display: none;">Aguarde, processando ...</span>
```

Quando o `button` ganha a classe `.onestepcheckout-place-order-button-disabled` ele fica da seguinte maneira:

```
<button type="button" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout onestepcheckout-place-order-button-disabled" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order Now'); ?>" id="onestepcheckout-place-order-button">
```

Eu queria fazer com que quando o `button` ganhasse essa classe adicional, o `span` ficasse com `display:block` ou em `.show()`. Pensei bastante em uma lógica para realizar isso, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Quando o `button` ganha essa classe?

Comment: @RafaelAugusto Essa classe somente serve para desabilitar o clique no botão e o mesmo ganha quando o cartão de crédito é verificado.

Comment: O span esta dentro ou fora do button?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Fora do `button`

Comment: Agora mudou de opinião ? hehehe, blz então a resposta do Sérgio deve resolver.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não exatamente haha. Acabei errando no que digitei, aí acabei fazendo isso novamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o botão tem a referida `class` usando `.hasClass`, após ele receber a `class`:

```
if($("#onestepcheckout-place-order-button").hasClass('onestepcheckout-place-order-button-disabled')){
  $("#process").show();
}
```

```js
$("button.button").addClass('onestepcheckout-place-order-button-disabled');

if($("#onestepcheckout-place-order-button").hasClass('onestepcheckout-place-order-button-disabled')){
  $("#process").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  type="button" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order Now'); ?>" id="onestepcheckout-place-order-button">Clique</button>
<span id="process" style="display: none;">Aguarde, processando ...</span>
```

Comment: O que estaria faltando seria um evento para que o código pudesse ser executado, pois o botão não ganha essa classe já no carregamento da página.

Comment: Mas mesmo colocando esse if no meu código, ele é executado no carregamento da página e não quando o `button` ganha essa classe.

Comment: O problema é que como o código não é meu, eu ainda não consegui localizar isso, quando ele faz essa ação de adicionar a classe. Ele adiciona a classe quando a verificação dos dados digitados pelo usuário sobre o seu cartão de crédito é verificado. E até agora também não encontrei nenhum tipo de evento para poder disparar essa ação ...

Comment: Com esse teste deu certo, porém só faltou esconder o botão novamente.

Comment: Não, a classe que o botão ganha faz ele adquirir o atributo `disabled`. Depois da verificação ter sido feita, o botão perde essa classe e quando acontecesse isso queria dar um `.hide()` no `span`.

Comment: Clique no botão para adicionar a classe e depois clique de novo para remover: Veja agora: https://jsfiddle.net/80w9xj50/4/

Comment: Deu certo, porém existe uma exceção que percebi. O código ele só é executado uma vez. Se alguma modificação for feita e a verificação acontecer novamente e a classe adicionada, o código não é executado por uma segunda vez.

Comment: Coloquei tudo dentro de uma função que será reinvocada: https://jsfiddle.net/80w9xj50/5/

Comment: Show! Deu certo! Muito obrigado por toda a ajuda e atenção!

Answer (score 5):

Podes fazer isso com o seletor de elemento adjacente `+`. Para fazer isso só com CSS tens de usar `!important` para o efeito do `display: none;` inline no elemento ser anulado.

Ficaria assim:
(o JavaScript é só para mudar a classe no exemplo)

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', () =>
  btn.classList.toggle('onestepcheckout-place-order-button-disabled')
);
```

```css
.onestepcheckout-place-order-button-disabled+span {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order Now'); ?>" id="onestepcheckout-place-order-button">Clica-me</button>
<span id="process" style="display: none;">Aguarde, processando ...</span>
```

Comment: Já ia ate comentando kkk, ai vi seu comentario, show!

Answer (score 0):

Se percebi o botão ja ganha a classe .onestepcheckout-place-order-button-disabled.
Então penso que apenas precisa adicionar o seguinte CSS:

```
button.span{
    display:none;
}
button.onestepcheckout-place-order-button-disabled span {
    display:block !important;
}
```